# Repeating a function on a matrix multiple times and summing resulting matrices

Tags: r, loops, matrix, memory, bioinformatics

I am running into issues writing code in R when trying to repeat a line of code multiple times.

I have written the following code:

```
rep(blank.matrix<-((distance(site.by.species[sample(nrow(site.by.species)),], method='jaccard')<=existing.jaccard.similarity)*1)+blank.matrix,times=100)
```

in which I am attempting to permute a site by species matrix:

```
site.by.species[sample(nrow(site.by.species)),]
```

then get a jaccard similarity matrix from this:

```
distance("", method='jaccard')
```

and then compare it against an existing similarity matrix where I want to find all of the values less than or equal to it

```
<=existing.jaccard.similarity
```

and then I want to run this 100 times - adding the 1's and 0's from each created matrix together so that I have an output that gives me the number of times my `existing.jaccard.similarity` values are less than are equal to my permuted values.

The issue I'm running into is that my matrix is quite large (8000x700) so while this code seems to run when I repeat <5 times, when I try to repeat a greater number of times I get the error:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size x Gb.

I was surprised by this because I thought I would only be storing the updated blank.matrix to memory - but I realize there are probably other ways to solve this problem through `apply()` or for loops. I appreciate any help with how to clean up this code!

Comment: Edit: I am realizing now that the rep() function isn't really even repeating that code, so maybe I am more lost than I had initially thought.

Comment: Perhaps you need `replicate(100, code_goes_here)` instead, it uses an actual `expression` which should do more of what you need.

Comment: I just tried this but it seems that it runs the jaccard similarity the right number of times but then for some reason the output matrix (blank.matrix) is filled with NA values after all of the runs, here is what I ran: replicate(2,
blank.matrix<-((distance(site.by.species[sample(nrow(site.by.species)),], method='jaccard')<=jaccard.similarity)*1)+blank.matrix
) I thought the blank.matrix would contain all of those trials added up but I must be missing something here. Thanks!

Comment: Do the assignment *outside*, as in `results <- replicate(2, distance(...))`?

Comment: `results<-replicate(2, ((distance(site_spe3[sample(nrow(site_spe3)),], method='jaccard')<=jaccard.similarity)*1))`    This is really close, however, it returns an array of each of the matrices where I would like to simply sum all together. I could sum them after running, but for just 2 replicates the resulting array is ~400mb when I would like to run 100-1000 times. My thoughts are that there must be some way to sum each resulting matrix as it is created so that the final result is just one summed matrix. Your help has been greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
repeat{
  results = ((distance(site.by.species[sample(nrow(site.by.species)),],method='jaccard')<=jaccard.similarity)*1) + results
   print(results[1,1])
   if (results[1,1] == 100){
     print("repeat loop ends");
     break
   }
}
```

I used the repeat function here because I was only looking to output a single matrix rather than all of the matrices together as an array which is what I was getting with the `replicate()` method. My `repeat` ends once the `results[1,1]` hits 100 because this element in the matrix is the similarity of the same site which will always be equal to the `jaccard.similarity` table ([2,2];[3,3];and so on would also work), so each run adds 1 to this column.

There are probably much easier ways to do this!